# Android Emulator error with VS 2019 on Windows 7 laptop

Tags: android-emulator, windows-7, visual-studio-2019

I have installed Android Emulator with VS 2019 on my Windows 7 Ultimate 32 Bit laptop. However, get below errors when trying to add new device.
**Android Emulator component is missing or incomplete therefore the device**
All error screenshots are attached here. Please advise , just unable to create or develop Android application in VS 2019
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
enter image description here
[image]

Comment: use 64Bit Windows 10

Comment: @magicandre1981  That will not be possible immediately. Will Window 7 not work ?

Comment: 32Bit support for emulator [was removed 2020](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#emu-win-32-support) and Windows 7 is also out of support for 1 years

Comment: Ok, I doubt my laptop will upgrade under to Windows 10 . See its low configuration , attached in my question above. Do you think I should go for a new laptop in that case ?

Comment: I don't see any HW specs in the topic.

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981 for quick responses. I have just attached my laptop screenshot. Kindly suggest. See 1st screenshot in above question

Comment: ok, this 1st Gen i3 is not supported in Windows 10. It is now over 10 years old. looks like it is time for a faster device with recent AMD Ryzen APU.

Comment: and you can also connect your real phone via USB and deploy the apps here to test it and use this [VS extension](https://github.com/pvdstel/scrcpy-vs) to show the phone as window inside of VS similar to emulator

Comment: Ok, will android development with Visual studio C# be possible in mobile device ?

Comment: yes, I only use my physical mobil phone (Google Pixel) for app deployment/debugging/testing